# php mongodb on BulkWriteException get Additional information

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using a schema validation on a collection, on a property to check that its type is integer.
In order to check that the schema validation is working well I try to put a string into that property.
Doing this throws an exception of type MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException with this messsage : `Document failed validation`

Everything is working as excepted but according to mongodb doc : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/schema-validation/specify-json-schema/#std-label-schema-validation-json

it is possible to have additional information and thus get the reason why this exception has been triggered (the description property of the failed validation).
I can't figure out how to get those additional information from BulkWriteException.
This is a code I use :

```
try {
    doSomething('string');//force validation to failed
} catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();// shows: Document failed validation
    var_dump($ex->getWriteResult()->getServer()->getInfo());// shows server info but not the error info
    foreach ($ex->getWriteResult()->getWriteErrors() as $error) {
        var_dump($error);// it is empty
    }
}
```

ps: I am using mongodb from this repo : https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the solution. For some reasons, my debugger was displaying an empty value for `var_dump($error);` but in fact it was the right object.
I can access the additional information by writing `$error->getInfo()`